# How do I change the texture of a specific copy of an object upon collision in Spritekit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision

When my main character sprite contacts a checkpoint sprite, I would like to change the texture of the checkpoint sprite. I am currently using the following code:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
    {

    SKPhysicsBody *firstBody, *secondBody;

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
    {

        firstBody = contact.bodyA;
        secondBody = contact.bodyB;
    }
    else
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB;
        secondBody = contact.bodyA;
    }

    if (secondBody.categoryBitMask == 4)
    {
        [secondBody setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"balloon_PNG3395.png"]];

    }
}
```

This code doesn't work because I am trying to use the setTexture method on a SKPhysicsBody (secondBody) rather than a SKSpriteNode. The difficulty that I am having is that secondBody refers to a specific spriteNode that has multiple copies all over the map, so I can't just reference it directly. I have all of these copies contained in an array, but I don't know how to reference the specific instance that was contacted to just change the texture of that one.

Does anyone have any ideas for changing the texture of a specific instance of a spriteNode when contact occurs on that copied instance? Could there potentially be another easier way to mark a specific copy of a spriteNode as having been contacted?

Comment: What do you mean by copies all over the map? An SKNode can be parented only once (ie. be shown once in the scene). So is this map your own abstraction to hold nodes by pointer reference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by pointer reference, but I've initiated several "checkpoint" objects all over the map and they're all on the map appearing simultaneously. They're all initiated from the same checkpoint.m file as copies and are all contained in a mutable array that's set as a property of the scene.

Comment: [(SKSpriteNode*)secondBody.node setTexture:..